# SOQL error with relationship

Tags: apex, soql

I have one query as below:

```
select id,functional_system_user__c,
       Test_Created_Date__c,
       Test_Login_Date__c,lastmodifieddate,name,
       isactive,Reactivation_Date__c,email,isportalenabled 
  from user where id='ABC'
```

Another query is :

```
select id,isfrozen,userid from userlogin where userid ='ABC'
```

I wanted isfrozen field to be included in 1st SOQL.I have written below query and i am getting error saying invalid relationship.

```
select id, functional_system_user__c, Test_Created_Date__c,  
       Test_Login_Date__c, isactive, Reactivation_Date__c, email,  
       isportalenabled,
       (select isfrozen from userlogin ) 
  from user where id='ABC'
```

Id of 1st SOQL is equal to userid of 2nd SOQL.

Comment: you can't subquery `userlogin` seems like limitation.. You can check in eclipse's salesforce schema If we can subquery or not..

Comment: I have checked on WorkBench, and it seems that UserLogin's field UserId is not really a relationship, only value. So you have to do 2 soql

Comment: But userid of userlogin table is same as id of user table.So is it possible to write.

Comment: as well as OwnerId on account is also the same as id of user id, you should be able to query all user accounts by (select Id,(Select Id From Accounts) From User). But you can not. Not every salesforce relation behave like custom field lookup/master-detail.

Comment: Can you post these comments as an answer, @kurunve?

Comment: @battery.cord unfortunately, I can not find any proofs/official docs of that. So there are no answer, only ideas and workarounds

Comment: @kurunve Go for an answer anyway, regardless of backing documentation it's a fair description of how the system works and you deserve the points for it!

Comment: yes kurunve-You have explained well enough as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem possible to subquery this child relationship. I ran the following:

```
for (ChildRelationship relationship : SObjectType.User.getChildRelationships())
{
    if (relationship.getChildSObject() == UserLogin.sObjectType)
    {
        system.debug(relationship.getField() + ' - ' + relationship.getRelationshipName());
    }
}
```

The results I got were:

> USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|LastModifiedById - null
>   USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|UserId - null

This means that while the relationship is there, it does not have a name you can use.

Contrast this with, for example, an attempt to subquery `AccountTeamMember` records. If I change the `SObjectType` I am looking for above, I get

> USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|CreatedById - null
>   USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|LastModifiedById - null
>   USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|UserId - AccountTeams

So I cannot subquery `AccountTeamMember` records based on `LastModifiedById` from a `User` query, but I can merge in the relationship name to look at any matches on `UserId`:

```
SELECT (SELECT Account.Name FROM AccountTeams) FROM User
```