# SOQL - UserLogin relationship from User

Tags: apex, soql, query, user, user-management

I am trying to check if a user is frozen but i can't figure out the relationship query. It seems like one doesn't exist even though there is a lookup.  This older post hints at it but I can't figure out how to form my query. 
[SOQL error with relationship](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106878/soql-error-with-relationship)

Tried all of these:

```
List<User> Users = new list<User>([
            SELECT Id,FirstName,LastName, (Select isFrozen FROM UserLogin)
            FROM User
            WHere LastLoginDate >= :SixtyDaysAgo
        ]);

      List<UserLogin> uLogins = new list<UserLogin>([
            Select Id, UserId, UserId.FirstName, UserId.LastName
            FROM UserLogin
            WHERE IsFrozen = FALSE
            AND LastLoginDate >= :SixtyDaysAgo
        ])

        List<UserLogin> uLogins = new list<UserLogin>([
            Select Id, UserId, (Select FirstName, LastName FROM User WHERE LastLoginDate >= :SixtyDaysAgo)
            FROM UserLogin
            WHERE IsFrozen = FALSE
        ])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a [`Left Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join):

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM User
WHERE Id IN (SELECT UserId FROM UserLogin WHERE IsFrozen = true)
```

Also note that the query syntax returns a `List<User>`, and you are being excessively verbose. No need to do `new List<User>([/*query*/])` where `[/*query*/]` will suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the syntax tip. Didn't realize that you could leave that off.

Comment: Do you think this code will work correctly? i am not sure how to test it.

Comment: //Get 60 Days Ago
        Date SixtyDaysAgo = date.today().addDays(-60);
        
        //Find users who have been inactive for sixty days so we can freeze their account. 
        List<UserLogin> uLogins = [
            SELECT ID FROM UserLogin
            WHERE UserId IN (Select Id,FirstName,LastName
                             FROM User 
                             WHERE LastLoginDate <= :sixtyDaysAgo
                             )
            AND isFrozen = FALSE
        ];

Comment: @Matt No, you need a `NOT IN (...)` clause, but you should ask a separate question for that! :)